# Shortest way of splitting a pandas DataFrame column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

**Inspiration**

In R, this is very easy

```
data("iris")
bartlett.test(Sepal.Length ~ Species,data = iris)
```

The important thing about the data set is that the column Sepal.Length is numerical, the species is categorical.

**Problem**

In Python `scipy.stats.bartlett` would need separate arrays for each species, see [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.bartlett.html).

What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

An easy way to get the dataset in python:

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
iris = pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],
                     columns= ["sepal.length","sepal.width","petal.length","petal.width"] + ['species'])
```

I really wanted this to work:

```
iris.groupby("species")["sepal.length"].apply(ss.bartlett)
```

but it didn't due to it needing multiple sample vectors.

Comment: where's the declaration for ss?

Comment: @Yuca `import scipy.stats as ss`

Comment: `iris.groupby("species").apply(lambda x : ss.bartlett(x['species'],x['sepal.length']))`

Comment: @Wen if you run this you get inf, I'm not familiar with bartlett so I'm staying away from this one

Comment: @Wen this passes the column `species` and `sepal.length`, but what I need is to split the column `sepal.length` into three arrays based on the values in the `species` column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the groupby pattern you can do a bit of manipulation and do this:

```
gb = iris.groupby('species')["sepal.length"]
ss.bartlett(*[gb.get_group(x).values for x in gb.groups])
```

the `*` unpacks the list into the function, the rest is just to get the groups into the right form for the function to take. As mentioned in the comments, the `.values` isn't needed here so we can write it as:

```
gb = iris.groupby('species')["sepal.length"]
ss.bartlett(*[gb.get_group(x) for x in gb.groups])
```

And just for completion, if you really want to do it in one line:

```
ss.bartlett(*[x[1] for x in iris.groupby('species')["sepal.length"]])
```

But I personally find that less readable.

Comment: It seems, that the `.values` is not needed, so this solution is even more cool than it looked like! I'm a little sad, that it needs two lines, but actually with data like this, where there's only one categorical column, I guess you'd immediately do a `groupby` anyway, so I guess it's okay :) (I'm teaching a statistics course, using `R` and in parallel I'm figuring out everything in python, since normally it's the language I use, and now that I found some nifty features of `pandas` I'm again thinking that probably python is better overall :D).

Comment: oh yeah, so this works: `ss.bartlett(*(gb.get_group(g) for g in gb.groups))`

Comment: Great yes good point, I normally default to `.values` as it gives you the numpy array object but in most cases like this it's not needed. Also don't know if you're aware but using the comprehension inside `()` instead of `[]`creates a generator object, which is fine in this case but gives you different properties than list comprehension which you might find interesting. Will update my answer with your findings.

Comment: @fbence if you want to do it in one line see my edit, I personally think there's a bit too much abstracted away to make it worth it